# How should I add a dynamic value in image url?

Tags: html, css, dom

I want to add a DOM dynamic ID into an image url. The current img src url has values, but I want to insert values through variables DOM objects.

Movie.Imdb is a variable that I want the img src to dynamically render.

```
<div id=imdb style="visibility: hidden;">{{movie.id}}</div>
              
<div  src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&h=600" ></div>
```

I want the image src url to be rendered as:

```
http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=+"imdb"+&h=600
```

So that it can be dynamic.

Comment: what do you want exactly..?

Comment: i want to create a url like this :   img src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=+"imdb" " instead of http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=88888..... i should be dynamic.... i want to pick up value using document.getElementById  which i will define in the script to take dynamic values....

Comment: img src url i want to use in my html

Comment: you want to create a `<img>` element as well...?

Comment: this is called templating. Use any templating engine to do such adventures...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use of `append()` and `attr()` jQuery

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var imageUrl = $("#imageUrl").attr("src");
$(".wrapper").append("<img src=" + imageUrl + ">")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="imageUrl" src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&h=600&apikey=6c3a2d45"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  src="http://img.omdbapi.com/?i="+movie.id+"&h=600" ></div>
```

This should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).